# Is my code utilizing proper Object Oriented features?

Tags: javascript, object-oriented, ecmascript-6

```
 class element {
   constructor(name){
    this.name = name;
   }
   createNew(){
    var elem = document.createElement(this.name);
    document.body.appendChild(elem);
   }
   setElementAttribute(attr_name, attr_value){
    this.attr_name = attr_name;
    this.attr_value = attr_value;
   }
   createNewWithAttribute(){
    var elem = document.createElement(this.name);
    document.body.appendChild(elem);
    elem.setAttribute(this.attr_name, this.attr_value);
   }
 }
 class elementWithText extends element {
   constructor(name, text){
    super(name);
    this.text = text;
   }
   createNew(){
   var elem = document.createElement(this.name);
   document.body.appendChild(elem);
   elem.innerHTML = this.text;
  }
   setElementAttribute(attr_name, attr_value){
    super.setElementAttribute(attr_name, attr_value); 
  }
   createNewWithAttribute(){
    var elem = document.createElement(this.name);
    document.body.appendChild(elem);
    elem.setAttribute(this.attr_name, this.attr_value);
    elem.innerHTML = this.text;
  }
}
   var inputBox = new element('input');
   inputBox.setElementAttribute('type','radio');
   inputBox.createNewWithAttribute();
   var heading = new elementWithText('h1','Hello World');
   heading.setElementAttribute('style','color: red;');
   heading.createNewWithAttribute();
```

Comment: One character of indent?  Really?  Is that considered good for code readability?  I would not approve a checkin with that indentation into my code repository.

Comment: It is not apparent why you need an new type object for either of these since the attribute value is just double stored (both on the DOM element and in the instance data).  A couple functions that take a couple arguments that operate on a DOM element could replace all this.  Or, you could use the jQuery model where you have an object that just contains a reference to the DOM element and some methods.

Comment: It would good if you told us what your code is doing first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I don't suggest encapsulating such standard functionality in classes unless you are just playing around or learning.
- I suggest renaming `element` to `ElementFactory` or `ElementSpawner` or something alike as it doesn't encapsulate a DOM element but creates and appends them. You then might want to `return` the created elements, too.
- Also, what happens when you call `createNewWithAttribute` without previous call to `setElementAttribute`? Shouldn't you rather keep an internal map of attributes and make their addition optional via `createNew(withAttributes = true)` parameter?
- Also, `elem.innerHTML = this.text` should probably be written as `elem.textContent = this.text` unless `text` means `html` in which case you should rename the class.
- Don't mix CamelCase (`elementWithText`) with unser_scores (`attr_value`) and preferably capitalize class names.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestions. I am just playing around with ES6 syntax, my intention behind asking this question was to know whether am I missing some concept related to OOP i.e. am I taking full advantage of code reusability, calling base class functions, inheritance etc. 
Thanks again for your valuable suggestions.

Comment: @AmirSaleem You might be interested in static factory methods: `class Factory { static createElement(name) { return document.createElement(name); } }` - this is a pretty common pattern.